# outputting csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I need some help outputting a file that I have just assigned a variable to to finish my code. I need some help fixing the bit below if get_bool_input() to output the file.

```
filename = class_name + ".csv"
csv.register_dialect('pipes', delimiter='|')

with open('filename.csv', 'a',newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    data=[['Name','Score'],
          [name,score]]
    a.writerows()


if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
    print filename
else:
    input ("Press any key to exit")
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is.  However, you appear to be using the `print` statement, which is Python 2, in which case you should use `raw_input()` rather than `input()`.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: it will not output my file.

Comment: You don't actually seem to be using the data variable anywhere!

Comment: See the docs for the CSV writer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer